# Relative and Absolute Positioning in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/WJve3/3/

How do I make `Object1` and `Object2` positioned both relative to the "title"?

The problem that I seem to have right now is that `Object1` is positioned relative to `title` and `Object2` is positioned relative to `Object1`

Comment: Please read: [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: What do you expect as output? That object 1 and object 2 are positioned on 1 line?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Can you please word It different, how you would like your output to be?

Comment: @NielsC yes for them to both be on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled "position"; and you need to use static positioning for Object1 and Object 2. Try this:

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 45%
}
.Object1 {
    position: absolute;
    top 0;
    left: 0;
}
.Object2 {
    position: absolute;
    top 0%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I center the title, and have the two Objects not have the left positioning be relative to the title?

Comment: Take them out of <div class="Title"> block

Comment: So how would I center the title and the objects and have the objects positioned relative to the title so that that objects are also centered and spaced apart?

Comment: It might be worth noting that static != absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one `</div>`

```
<DIV class="title">
    <h1><font face="Comic Sans MS" color=black><center>Title</center></font></h1>
    <DIV style="position: relative;"> 
        <DIV class="Object1">
            <h2><font face="Comic Sans MS" color=black><center>Object1</center></font></h2>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="Object2">
            <h2><font face="Comic Sans MS" color=black><center>Object2</center></font></h2>
        </DIV> <!-- MISSING /DIV -->
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

And misspelled "position"

Answer (score 0):

You could use this CSS to put the objects on 1 line

```
.title {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 300px;
}
.Object1 {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
.Object2 {
   width: 50%;
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: How would I center the title and the objects and have the objects positioned relative to the title so that that objects are also centered and spaced apart?

Comment: Can you make an image which explains what you mean?

Comment: Basically what i want to do, is what you wrote above, but instead of having the title at "left: 45%", how can i have it always centered no matter how I reshape a window browser size?

Comment: Note: to use margin: 0 auto you'll need to set the width of the title div

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a positions if you need objects next to each other:

```
    .title {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
      left: 45%
    }
   .Object1 {
      float:left
    }
    .Object2 {
      float:left;
      margin-left:20px;
    }
```

or you can give the title div a position relative and give object1 and 2 the absolute positioning. this way you will be able to position your objects inside title div.